# How to Change Column Width for All Word Tables at Once?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a lot of tables (around a 100) all of them following the sequence:
1 column in the first row, 4 in the second and third row, and then 1 again in the fourth and so on.
I would like to make the first row with one column 18 cm in width which would be the width to all the tables as well, and then in the second and third row 1 cm, 11 cm, 3.5 cm, 2.5 cm for the columns respectively. Is there any way to do this at once?

Comment: This would probably require a VBA macro, which wouldn't be easy.